# How to achieve this type of format when writing pseudo-code?

Tags: algorithms, pseudocode

I want to achieve the following type of format when writing pseudo-code, but I am struggling to achieve it with `algorithm` package:

[image: Pseudo-code]

Is this written with the `algorithm` package, or is it another package?

Comment: Could you please show a minimal working example with what you got so far?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it via `listings` package.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95, 0.95, 0.96}
\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

% start pseudo-code
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python]
        (*@$Code goes here$@*)  
\end{lstlisting}
```